# Is there a built in adjustment to limit how far these crank windows open?

Tags: windows, security, child-safety

I need to prevent these windows from opening too wide.

I have a plan to drill into the bracket and insert a bolt to limit the range of motion, but before I start modifying I want to rule out a built in limiting/control mechanism I might be missing.

There is a clip and an unused hole in one area, but I don't see any way to use them to achieve what I need.

[image: full crank mechanism]

[image: close up of rear section, possible adjusters, clip and unused hole]

Comment: The clip might (or might not) be a limiter to affect whether the window opens to "egress" or further for cleaning (while having less clear area than at the egress opening size.) I have different windows with a somewhat similar clip. Speaking of which, if they **are** egress windows, you have to proceed carefully or may not be able to legally modify them this way.

Comment: Based on their locations they are not suitable for egress, even in an emergency, and that's related to why I need to limit them, they are very dangerous as they currently are.

Comment: Just because the windows open, does not mean you have to climb through them...

Comment: Any chance you can add a decorative chain to the frame opposite the hinges and window to stop the opening process?

Comment: @SolarMike I'll tell my 2yr old

Comment: @JACK thought about a chain but I prefer the bolt solution for a variety of reasons, might still change my mind